# playing selected video from listbox plays multiple videos at same time

Tags: c#

i am new in C#
when i play selected different video from listbox. I plays both previously playing video and current video at the same time. What should i do for that only selected video is being played.

My code is below:-

```
namespace videoplayer
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Video vid;
        string currentmedia;
        string[] s=new string[5];

        public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            openFileDialog1.FileNames.CopyTo(s, 0);
            foreach (string l in s)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(l);
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            current=(s[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);
            vid = new Video(current);
            vid.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time your selection index changes, a new instance of a `Video` is created.

I would suggest you to create one global instance and use that to handle all the video files.

Something like this :

```
Video player;
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    current=(s[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);

    if (player != null && player.Playing)
        player.Stop();

    if (player != null)
        player.Dispose();

    player = new Video(current);
    player.Play();            

}
```

Comment: When I create one global instance of Video, compiling this shows the error:- 'Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video does not contain a constructor that take '0' argument. How can I fix this problem.

Comment: @user2226431 - fixed! now its proper code instead of pseudo-code!

Comment: Add the argument? Which should be the current video. So if you don't have a video, simply assign null for it (Nothing in VB)